# Vuetify snackbar conditional

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Does someone know how display a snackbar depending of the result of answer of server.

For example, if submit is ok, display success green snack bar with success message but if I have a error I need to display a red error snack bar with a binding of the error message.

I think I need to pass through a method to display it.
I want do this in just one snackbar like this.

```
<v-snackbar
    :color = "color" 
> {{text here}}
</v-snackbar
```

example of server post

```
http.post(apiAdresse, objectToPost)
   .then(() => {
     something to do here})
   .catch(error => {
     console.log(error)};)
```

edit code:

```
        <v-snackbar
                :color="snackbar.color"
                v-model="snackbar.show">
            <v-icon class="snackIcon">{{snackbar.icon}}</v-icon>
            {{ snackbar.message }}
            <v-btn
                    dark
                    text
                    @click="snackbar = false"
            >
                Close
            </v-btn>

        </v-snackbar>
```

When I'm clicking on close btn

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'show' in false"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll do it like this:

```
<template>
    <!-- Set the color, v-model and message values in the data prop -->
    <v-snackbar :color="snackbar.color" v-model="snackbar.show">
        {{ snackbar.message }}
    </v-snackbar>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            snackbar: {
                show: false,
                message: null,
                color: null
            }
        }),
        methods: {
            submitAction() {
                http.post(apiAdresse, objectToPost)
                .then(() => {
                    this.snackbar = {
                        message: 'Your success message',
                        color: 'success',
                        show: true
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.snackbar = {
                        message: 'Your error message',
                        color: 'error',
                        show: true
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

You're getting `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'show' in false"` because you are trying to update the snackbar object to a boolean. You should do this instead:

```
<v-btn dark text @click="snackbar.show = false">
   Close
</v-btn>
```

Comment: Now I have this message on my console

Comment: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'show' in false"

Comment: I just use the code you give me, before that it was okay, I just add a btn to snack bar, I edit my code to see it

Comment: Updated my answer